# Why does int1 exist in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

So I understand the need for int2, int3, etc... and I understand the need for int. What I don't really understand is int1. It would seem to just be worse at doing what an int already does.

So why does int1 exist in CUDA?

Comment: So you can template and consistently  use `.x` access without breaking things.

Comment: Seems like a valid answer. What kinds of operations would only relay on the first dimension though?

Comment: The magnitude of a vector has a proper definition regardless of the number of components, I think? I'll bet @njuffa or someone else can give you a more satisfying answer.

Comment: I have never used `int1`, wasn't involved in the creation of this type, and have not pondered this question before, but what @RobertCrovella stated above seems like a reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible benefit of offering an `int1` vector type is that a function could be templated for various vector lengths (e.g. `int1`, `int2`, `int3`, `int4`), and still give proper behavior when selecting the `.x` element:

```
template <typename T>
int return_first_element(T d){
  return d.x;}
```

The above construct would not work for `T = int`.

I don't have an example of compelling use of such a construct, however.